# Will the public key generated in android keystore remains the same

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api

I have the below requirement.

1. While registering for fingerprint option user will be providing the username password and then the fingerprint.
2. We need to generate key in android store and pass that to server(username, password and the key generated).
   3.In server they will save this key corresponding to the username and password.
   Whenever the user tries to login with finger pint, from client side we need to take the key once fingerprint authentication is successful and pass that to server.
   4.In server they will check the table row(server DB) in which that key is already been saved and will use that corresponding username and password.

My doubt is will that key remains the same. We are passing the key to server side while registering for fingerprint t along with username password. So if again when the user tries to login and creates a key will it remain the same.

Comment: No its not possible

Comment: The key will (read: _should_) get invalidated if you remove the fingerprint or enroll another fingerprint. If that occurs you'll have to ask the use to go through the registration process again.